# npm install not updating the node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

My package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "custom-lib": "ssh+giturl.com#v1.0.0"
  }
```

Now when I change the custom-lib version to **1.0.2** and do the **npm install** the node_modules are not getting updated. They still use the v1.0.0 version only and in package-lock.json the version also points to the old v1.0.0. Please note I tried removing node_modules and did the npm install but that didn't work.

Removing package-lock.json seems to work but that is not the ideal way of doing it. The npm update also working properly but I don't understand the problem with the npm install.

Node.js  Version: v18.13.0
npm version v9.3.0

I am using a Macbook Pro M2(macOS v13.3). The same way it used to work earlier in my linux machine.

Comment: are you changing `#v1.0.0` to `#v1.0.2`?

Comment: try: `npm install "ssh+giturl.com#v1.0.2"`. if you dont use quotes, bash will think everything after the `#` is a comment and ignore it.

Comment: @datashaman thanks this seems to work but sometimes I do have to install multiple repo's

Answer (score 0):

I deleted `package-lock.json` and the `node_modules` folder then:

- Commands:

```bash
ncu -u
```

[it updates `package.json` to the required version]

```bash
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

For me it regenerated the `node_modules` folder with  the updated version of the packages.